# Laravel. Show accepted friends for both users

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make sure that when user sends friend requests and another user accept it the friendlist will change for both users. Not only for the one who accepted the request. This is the problem. When user accepts the friend request the friend appears in his friendlist but not in the one's who sent friend request.

This is my controller function:

```
   public function add($id) // Add friends
   {
       $friend = new Friend();
       $friendId = User::where('id', $id)->first();
       $friend->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $friend->friend_id = $friendId->id;
       $friend->save();
       return redirect('/');
   }
```

Shows friend requests

```
public function showRequests()
{
        $requests = Friend::where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('accepted', '=', 0)->get();
        return view('users.friends.requests', compact('requests'));
}
```

Accepts friend request

```
public function accept($id)
{
    $friend = Friend::where('id', $id)->first();
    $friend->accepted = 1;
    $friend->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Shows friendlist

```
public function show()
{
    $friends = Friend::where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('accepted', '=', '1')->get();
    return view('users.friends.show', compact('friends'));
}
```

The relationships. User.php:

```
public function friend()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Friend');
}
```

Friend.php:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Taylor actually mentions this specific example on a GitHub issue so I'd probably go with that https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding a [pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)?
You can easily make pivots by using [Laracasts/Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended).

Once you create the pivot table, you'll do something like

```
public function add(...) { // Add friends
   $friend1 = User::find(1);
   $friend2 = User::find(2);
   $friend1->friends()->attach($friend2);
}
```

Then to get the relationship, you'll do:

```
public function show($id) {
    $user = User::find($id)
    return $user->friends()->get()
}
```

And your accepted/pending/denied requests can be simple columns in your pivot table.

You'll also have to implement the `friends()` function for the `User` Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
...
    public function friends() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: friends table in database have these fields: "user_id", "friend_id", "accepted" is it not enough ?

Comment: @labasGamePagevisogero but what if one `User` is friends with multiple other Users? how will you save all of their ids in your `friend_id` column? Maybe I'm wrong, but I think of the friend-friend relationship as a 2-way relationship, so then which friend should maintain the `friend_id` and how are you going to know that... You'll also have issues with searching and sorting later.

Comment: Okay. So should I delete my "friends" table and create new table like "friend_user"?

Comment: @labasGamePagevisogero yup. Read up on the documentation for `Laracasts/Generators`, because your pivot table is going to need more columns (maybe a `$table->smallInteger('request_status')->default(0)` for pending/accepted status, etc...)

Comment: So there should be columns: "friend_1" and "friend_2" ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked with only `friends` table.

```
public function friendsOfMine()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

public function friendOf()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

public function friends()
{
    return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get()->merge($this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
public function show()
{
    $friends = Auth::user()->friend()->where('accepted', '=', '1')->get();
    dd($friends);
}
```

Comment: You should always offer explanations of the code you are writing. Code only answers aren't very useful for future readers